# ESP32 condição aberto para repetição de mensagem telegram

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Estou tentando fazer com que depois de 1 minuto na condição "open" o sistema envie mensagens sem parar no telegram, tentei usar o RISING, mas não deu certo.

```
void setup() {
   // Read the current door state
  pinMode(reedSwitch, INPUT_PULLUP);
  state = digitalRead(reedSwitch);

//pinMode(motionSensor, INPUT_PULLUP);
  // Set LED state to match door state
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(led, state);
  
  // Set the reedswitch pin as interrupt, assign interrupt function and set CHANGE mode
//  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(motionSensor), detectsMovement, RISING);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(reedSwitch), changeDoorStatus, CHANGE);
 
void loop() {
  if (changeState){
    unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
    if(currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) {
      previousMillis = currentMillis;
      // If a state has occured, invert the current door state   
        state = !state;
        if(state) {
          doorState = "closed";
        }
        else{
          doorState = "open";  
        }

        digitalWrite(led, state);
        changeState = false;
        Serial.println(state);
        Serial.println(doorState);
        
        //Send notification
        bot.sendMessage(CHAT_ID, "The door is " + doorState, "");
        
  }  
 }
}
```

Comment: Sobre o fechamento e possibilidade de reabertura, as instruções [já foram passadas da primeira vez que perguntou](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/559160/70). Você pode **restaurar** aquela postagem e **editar**, fazendo os ajustes necessários. Tendo atendido aos requisitos, a postagem pode ser reaberta e receber respostas. Para evitar duplicação de informação, o espaço dos comentários daqui está bloqueado, mas está disponível na postagem original.